# XSL: Unable to replace a character by newline character

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where I have to read some data and then reformat such that each part of the data is in new line.
For instance, the data I have is:

**dataLine1* dataLine2* dataLine3* dataLine4* dataLine5**

and result I expect is:


**dataLine1
* dataLine2
* dataLine3
* dataLine4
* dataLine5**

So basically, it boils down to **replacing * with 'newlinecharater*'**. However, I am still at beginners level in XSL and not sure how to achieve this.

The code I have is:

```
<!-- START: Code to replace the data within a string since I am working on XSLT 0.1 -->
   <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
<!-- END: Code to replace the data within a string since I am working on XSLT 0.1 -->  
<xsl:variable name="CPC" select="./_line_item_comment"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($CPC,'!$!')" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'*'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$newline" /> <!-- Here I have to give the newline character -->
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Shikhar

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transaction>
    <data_xml currency="USD" language="English">
        <document buyer_company_id="4118171" buyer_user_id="48522367" data_type="3" document_id="4180721" document_number="3" document_var_name="line_process" supplier_company_id="4118171">
            <config label="Configurable" repeatable="true">
                <_config_attr_info />
            </config>
            <model label="Model" repeatable="true">
                <_model_id label="Model ID" />
                <_model_segment_id label="Model Segment ID" />
                <_model_product_line_id label="Model Product Line ID" />
                <_model_supplier_company_id label="Model Supplier Company ID" />
                <_model_name label="Model Name" />
                <_model_segment_name label="Model Segment Name" />
                <_model_product_line_name label="Model Product Line Name" />
                <_model_product_line_attributes />
                <_model_base_price display_precision="2" label="Model Base Price" />
                <_model_attributes />
                <_model_supplier_company_name label="Model Supplier Company Name" />
                <_model_bom label="Model BOM" />
                <_model_variable_name label="Model Variable Name" />
                <_model_product_line_var_name label="Model Product Line Variable Name" />
                <_model_segment_var_name label="Model Segment Variable Name" />
            </model>
            <part label="Part" repeatable="true">
                <_partner_entity_id label="Partner Entity Id" />
                <_part_units label="Part Units" />
                <_part_id label="Part ID">73454089</_part_id>
                <_part_supplier_company_id label="Part Supplier Company ID">4118171</_part_supplier_company_id>
                <_part_number label="Part Number">SS-29794-29</_part_number>
                <_part_desc label="Part Description">TUBULAR-INTERMEDIATE JT,LS,20, 20.000 X 0.625 W, LS BOX X 20.000 X 0.625 LS PIN,API 5L X56 SAW, 36 FT NOM</_part_desc>
                <_part_base_price display_precision="2" label="Part Base Price">0</_part_base_price>
                <_part_lead_time label="Part Lead Time">N/A</_part_lead_time>
                <_part_supplier_company_name label="Part Supplier Company Name">GEOG Energy Installation Field Services</_part_supplier_company_name>
                <_part_custom_field1 label="Family" />
                <_part_custom_field2 label="Cost" />
                <_part_custom_field3 label="Max Discount" />
                <_part_custom_field4 label="Maintenance %" />
                <_part_custom_field5 label="Part Custom Field 5" />
                <_part_custom_field6 label="Part Custom Field6" />
                <_part_custom_field7 label="Part Custom Field7" />
                <_part_custom_field8 label="Part Custom Field8" />
                <_part_custom_field9 label="Part Custom Field9">Offshore</_part_custom_field9>
                <_part_custom_field10 label="Part Custom Field10">SC&amp;P</_part_custom_field10>
                <_part_custom_field11 label="Part Custom Field11" />
                <_part_custom_field12 label="Part Custom Field12" />
                <_part_custom_field13 label="Part Custom Field13" />
                <_part_custom_field14 label="Part Custom Field14" />
                <_part_custom_field15 label="Part Custom Field15" />
                <_part_drawing_position label="Drawing Position" />
                <_part_custom_field16 label="Part Custom Field 16" />
                <_part_custom_field17 label="Part Custom Field17" />
                <_part_direct_buy label="Direct Buy">1</_part_direct_buy>
                <_part_extended_desc_1 label="Part Extended Description 1" />
                <_part_extended_desc_2 label="Part Extended Description 2" />
                <_part_custom_field18 label="Part Custom Field18" />
                <_part_custom_field19 label="Part Custom Field19" />
                <_part_custom_field20 label="Part Custom Field20" />
                <_part_custom_field21 label="Part Custom Field21">29794-29</_part_custom_field21>
                <_part_custom_field22 label="Part Custom Field22" />
                <_part_custom_field23 label="Part Custom Field23" />
                <_part_custom_field24 label="Part Custom Field24" />
                <_part_custom_field25 label="Part Custom Field25" />
                <_part_custom_field26 label="Part Custom Field26" />
                <_part_custom_field27 label="Part Custom Field27" />
                <_part_custom_field28 label="Part Custom Field28" />
                <_part_custom_field29 label="Part Custom Field29" />
                <_part_custom_field30 label="Part Custom Field30" />
            </part>
            <price label="Price" repeatable="true">
                <_price_quantity label="Quantity">1</_price_quantity>
                <_price_override_quantity label="Override Quantity">false</_price_override_quantity>
                <_price_list_price_each display_precision="2" label="Guideline Price">0</_price_list_price_each>
                <_price_override_price display_value="No" label="Override Price">No</_price_override_price>
                <_price_subtotal display_precision="2" label="Subtotal">0</_price_subtotal>
                <_price_discount_percent label="Discount %">0.00</_price_discount_percent>
                <_price_total_discount display_precision="2" label="Total Discount">0</_price_total_discount>
                <_price_net_price display_precision="2" label="Net Price">0</_price_net_price>
                <_price_override_discount display_value="None" label="Override Discount">None</_price_override_discount>
                <_price_discount_comment label="Discount Comment" />
                <_price_configurable_price display_precision="2" label="Configurable Price">0</_price_configurable_price>
                <_price_component_prices />
            </price>
            <_document_number label="Document Number">3</_document_number>
            <_parent_doc_number label="Parent Document Number">2</_parent_doc_number>
            <_parent_line_item label="Parent Line Item">SC&amp;P</_parent_line_item>
            <sfProductId_line label="sfProduct Id" />
            <_sequence_number label="Line #">2</_sequence_number>
            <costEa_line display_precision="2" label="Cost Ea">0</costEa_line>
            <extendedCost_line display_precision="2" label="Extended Cost">0</extendedCost_line>
            <extendedList_line display_precision="2" label="Extended List">0</extendedList_line>
            <discount_line label="Discount">0.0</discount_line>
            <discountType_line display_value="%" label="Discount Type">%</discountType_line>
            <lockStandardDiscount_line display_value="True" label="Lock Standard Discount">true</lockStandardDiscount_line>
            <maxDiscountPercent_line label="Max Discount %">0.0</maxDiscountPercent_line>
            <discount2_line label="Discount2 (Display)" />
            <extendedDiscount_line display_precision="2" label="Extended Discount">0</extendedDiscount_line>
            <netPriceEach_line display_precision="2" label="Net Price Each">0</netPriceEach_line>
            <netMarginAmt_line display_precision="2" label="Net Margin">0</netMarginAmt_line>
            <netMarginAmtEach_line display_precision="2" label="Net Margin Each" />
            <netMarginPercent_line label="Net Margin %">0.0</netMarginPercent_line>
            <optional_line display_value="No" label="Optional">false</optional_line>
            <_price_book_var_name label="Price Book Variable Name">_default_price_book</_price_book_var_name>
            <_is_line_item_mandatory label="Is Line Item Mandatory">true</_is_line_item_mandatory>
            <extendedNetPrice_line display_precision="2" label="Extended Net Price">0</extendedNetPrice_line>
            <listPrice_line display_precision="2" label="List Price">0</listPrice_line>
            <customGroup_line display_value="1" label="Custom Group">1</customGroup_line>
            <approval_line display_value="No" label="Approval">false</approval_line>
            <discountPercent_line label="Discount %">0.0</discountPercent_line>
            <_original_document_number label="Original Document Number">-1</_original_document_number>
            <discountAmt_line display_precision="2" label="Discount $">0</discountAmt_line>
            <family_line label="Family" />
            <_reconfiguration_date label="Reconfiguration Date">1970-01-01 00:00:00</_reconfiguration_date>
            <_last_modified_date label="Last Modified Date">2015-12-20 04:07:33</_last_modified_date>
            <maintenancePercent_line label="Maintenance %">0.0</maintenancePercent_line>
            <_is_recommended_price label="Is Price Recommended">true</_is_recommended_price>
            <maintenanceSubtotal_line display_precision="2" label="Maintenance Subtotal">0</maintenanceSubtotal_line>
            <outputGroupName_line label="Output Group Name" />
            <outputGroupDescription_line label="Output Group Description" />
            <outputGroupSubtotal_line label="Output Group Subtotal" />
            <outputGroupNumber_line label="Output Group Number" />
            <outputListPrice_line display_precision="2" label="Output List Price" />
            <outputNetPriceEach_line display_precision="2" label="Output Net Price Each" />
            <outputExtendedNetPrice_line display_precision="2" label="Output Extended Net Price" />
            <outputGroupDiscount_line display_precision="2" label="outputGroupDiscount_line" />
            <outputSequenceNumber_line label="Output Sequence Number" />
            <tech1 label="tech1" />
            <currency label="Currency" />
            <model_line label="Model" />
            <_line_item_comment label="Line Item Comments">bb!$!20" INTERMEDIATE JOINT
* 20" x 0.625 "API 5L GR X-56 SAW pipe
* 40+/- 2FT  in length/joint
* LS (70 KSI), box up x pin down
* 100% Volumetric or radiographic inspection of connector girth weld to API 1104
* Connectors supplied with protectors</_line_item_comment>
            <_line_item_spare_rule_var_name label="Spare Rule recommended the Line Item">0</_line_item_spare_rule_var_name>
            <totalGenricCost_line display_precision="2" label="TotalGenricCost" />
            <fServFirmPriceMSADisc_line label="Special Pricing Agreement Discount" />
            <fServFirmPriceLTACustNum_line label="SPA Customer #" />
            <mSADiscountRepairs_line label="Special Pricing Agreement Discount">0.0</mSADiscountRepairs_line>
            <lTACustomerRepairs_line label="SPA Customer #" />
            <freightCostRepairs_line display_precision="2" label="Freight Cost" />
            <eS104MarkupRepairs_line label="Freight Markup (%)">20.0</eS104MarkupRepairs_line>
            <freightPriceRepairs_line display_precision="2" label="Freight Price" />
            <mSADiscountRepGen_line label="Special Pricing Agreement Discount">0.0</mSADiscountRepGen_line>
            <lTACustomerRepGen_line label="SPA Customer #" />
            <freightCostRepGen_line display_precision="2" label="Freight Cost" />
            <eS104MarkupRepGen_line label="Freight Markup (%)">20.0</eS104MarkupRepGen_line>
            <unitListInSelectedCurrencyMCS_line display_precision="2" label="Unit List in Selected Currency" />
            <mSADiscountMCS_line label="Special Pricing Agreement Discount" />
            <lTACustomerMCS_line label="MSA Customer #" />
            <dOALevel_line label="DOA Level">0</dOALevel_line>
            <currency_line display_value="USD" label="Currency">USD</currency_line>
            <deviationReason_line label="Deviation Reason" />
            <standardTasksTextArea_line label="Standard Tasks" />
            <editStandardTasksTxtArea_line label="Edit Standard Tasks" />
            <editStandardTasksReason display_value="Published Standard" label="Reason">Published Standard</editStandardTasksReason>
            <costFSFirmPrice_line display_precision="2" label="Cost Adjustment" />
            <options_line display_value="False" label="Display Only">false</options_line>
            <costGrid_line display_precision="2" label="Cost">0</costGrid_line>
            <cMGrid_line label="CM%" />
            <editStandardTasksRichText_line label="Edit Standard Tasks" />
            <standardTasksRTF_line label="Standard Tasks" />
            <editStandardTasksCheck_line display_value="False" label="Edit Standard Tasks">false</editStandardTasksCheck_line>
            <cycleTime_line label="Cycle Time" />
            <eS104Markup label="Freight Markup" />
            <materialPricingGroup label="Material Pricing Group">EM</materialPricingGroup>
            <mORAtQuotation label="MOR at Quotation" />
            <sizeOfOrder label="Size of Order" />
            <targetCM label="Target CM%" />
            <cost2GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost2" />
            <cost3GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost3" />
            <cost1GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost1" />
            <cost4GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost4" />
            <cost5GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost5" />
            <cost6GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost6" />
            <cost7GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost7" />
            <cost8GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost8" />
            <cost9GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost9" />
            <cost10GT_line display_precision="2" label="Cost10" />
            <deliveryTermsLine_line label="Delivery Terms" />
            <guidelinePriceMCSModel_line display_precision="2" label="Guideline Price" />
            <sellingPriceMCSModel_line display_precision="2" label="Selling Price" />
            <freightPriceMCSModel_line display_precision="2" label="Freight Price" />
            <workScopeForRepairs_line label="WorkScope" />
            <workScopeFlagRepairs_line display_value="False" label="WorkScope Flag">false</workScopeFlagRepairs_line>
            <wORKPACKAGEName_line label="WORKPACKAGE" />
            <opportunityCurrencyExchangeRate_line label="Opportunity Currency Exchange Rate">1.0</opportunityCurrencyExchangeRate_line>
            <modelNameCoreModel_line label="Model Name" />
            <currencyCoreModel_line label="Currency" />
            <mORCoreModel_line label="MOR for Model" />
            <guidelinePriceCoreMOdel_line display_precision="2" label="Guideline Price" />
            <sellingPriceCoreModel_line display_precision="2" label="Selling Price" />
            <proposalType_line label="Proposal Type">Budgetary</proposalType_line>
            <descriptionMCSNew_line label="Description" />
            <tILInfo_line label="TIL Info" />
            <genericScopeCost_line display_precision="2" label="Generic Scope Cost">0</genericScopeCost_line>
            <tILInfo2_line label="TIL Info" />
            <productInfo_Bently_Line label="ProductInfo_Bently_Line" />
            <modelOrLineDiscount display_value="Line" label="Model/Line">false</modelOrLineDiscount>
            <guidelinePrice_line display_precision="2" label="Guideline Price">0</guidelinePrice_line>
            <sellingPrice_line display_precision="2" label="Selling Price" />
            <parentModel_line label="Parent Model" />
            <parentProductLine_line label="Parent Product Line" />
            <unitPrice_line display_precision="2" label="Unit Price">0</unitPrice_line>
            <productTotal display_precision="2" label="product total" />
            <pGSGASRepairsWorkScopeTasksListRTE label="pGSGASRepairsWorkScopeTasksListRTE" />
            <pGSCMPartDesciptionSummup_forDocEng label="pGSCMPartDesciptionSummup_forDocEng" />
            <syncid_line label="Synchronization Id" />
            <externalId_line label="ExternalId">3-91845613</externalId_line>
            <productGpTotal display_precision="2" label="ProductGpTotal" />
            <opptyDriver_SS_line label="Oppty Driver" />
            <productService_SS_line label="Product Service" />
            <partNumber_line label="Part Number" />
            <extendedCompareDiscount_line label="extendedCompareDiscount_line">0.0</extendedCompareDiscount_line>
            <site_ds_line label="site_ds_line" />
            <warehouse_ds_line label="warehouse_ds_line" />
            <originalsite_ds_line label="OriginalSite" />
            <sequenceNum_ds_line label="SequenceNum" />
            <productCMPercent_line display_precision="2" label="Product CM%">0</productCMPercent_line>
            <cost_line display_precision="2" label="cost" />
            <dispenserBrandImage_line label="NOT IN USE" />
            <dispenserImageSubBrand_line label="NOT IN USE" />
            <quantity_SS_line display_precision="0" label="quantity_SS_line">1</quantity_SS_line>
            <sequenceNumber_bm_line label="Sequence Number" />
            <technicalDescription_DRL_line label="Technical Description" />
            <reconfigureFlag_line label="reconfigureFlag_line">false</reconfigureFlag_line>
            <controlsCostPriceReport_line label="Controls Cost Price Report" />
            <LineItemUOM_Line label="Line Item UOM" />
            <commentsSCP_SS_line label="commentsSCP_SS_line" />
            <nonstdPNReasonCode_SS_line label="NonstdPNReasonCode_SS_line">Customer Requirement (Quality Requirement)</nonstdPNReasonCode_SS_line>
            <grossMargin_line label="Gross Margin" />
            <priceLock_SS_line display_value="false" label="Price Lock">false</priceLock_SS_line>
            <_pricing_engine_info />
        </document>
    </data_xml>
</transaction>
```

Comment: Can you show the exact input you are using, please? In your XSLT fragment, it is looking for a `_line_item_comment` element to provide the text string, you see. Also, can you show the exact output you expect (Is it really text, or did you actually want HTML)? In particular, you say you want to replace `*` with a new line, but your expected output is still showing `*`. Thank you!

Comment: Show minimal but complete samples of XML input and XSLT code to allow us to reproduce the problem. Which output format do you want, HTML, XML, plain text?

Comment: @MartinHonnen; I have added the input XML. Thanks!

Comment: Well I asked for a minimal but complete sample to allow us to reproduce the problem, when I take your snippets to construct one at http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9t then the replacement is done. Of course there the output is plain text, you will need to tell us which format you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen; Thanks for the reply. Your code is working fine in the editor but not in my application. The expected out in my case is HTML. Can you please suggest what change I need to make?

Comment: I have written an answer explaining the probable cause of the problem and how to remedy it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually in HTML a newline character inside of an element is not rendered as a line break, that has nothing to do with XSLT, it is just how HTML works. If you want an explicit line break in HTML then use the `br` element, e.g. `<br/>`. So in your template replace `<xsl:value-of select="$by" />` with `<xsl:copy-of select="$by"/>` and call the template with `<xsl:with-param name="by"><br/></xsl:with-param>`, then make sure you use `<xsl:copy-of select="$myVar"/>`.

Here is the adapted sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">


<xsl:variable name="CPC" select="./_line_item_comment"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($CPC,'!$!')" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'*'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="by"><br/></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$myVar"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

As an alternative, HTML renders newlines as line breaks inside `<pre style="white-space: pre">...</pre>`. So if you want to use the existing code then use e.g.

```
<pre style="white-space: pre"><xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/></pre>
```

Comment: For some strange reason, even this code is not working for me. Basically, this code should format the element (myVar), which is nothing but value in the cell of a table. Also, the application I am working on. I am not writing complete XSL code. I just have to write what we call as "XSL Code Snippet". Thats the reaosn I can not copy and paste your code completely. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, then tag the question appropriately with a tag denoting the "application" you are working with, maybe someone then can tell you what to do. http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9t/1 is the conversion of the earlier sample to produce HTML `br` elements and works fine there.